# Return Mapping Table Value based on multiple values condition in a single 'Record'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a mapping table (shown below) that I'd like to return the 'Mapping Result' value based on conditions:

**1.MAPPING**

| Major Code | Minor Code | Mapping Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-* | 01;02;04 | Cash |
| 1-199 | 02 | Petty Cash |
| 1-* | 05 | Accounts Receivables |
| 1-999 | 06 | Inventory |
| 1-5*;1-6* | 07;08 | Supplies |
| 1-* | * | !!!Missing |

The conditions are listed looks at the values of 'Major Codes' and 'Minor Codes'. These are AND conditions.

For example, if major codes is like 1-* with minor codes 01, 02 or 03 then it's Cash.
[Major Code] Like '1-%' AND ([Minor Code] = '01' OR [Minor Code] = '02' OR [Minor Code] = '03')

However, notice that if it's 1-199 with minor code 02, then it should return as Petty Cash instead of Cash

If major code is 1-999 and minor code is 06 then it's Inventory

If major code is like 1-5* with minor code 07 or 08  OR  major code is like 1-6* with minor code 07 or 08 then it's Supplies.

Otherwise return !!!Missing (major code is 1-* and minor code could be any value EXCEPT 01,02,03,04,05,06,07 and 08)

So assume if I have another MAIN table, my desired result for 'Mapping Result' coming from the MAPPING table would be;

**2.MAIN TABLE**

| Major Code | Minor Code | Mapping Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-001 | 04 | Cash |
| 1-199 | 02 | Petty Cash |
| 1-250 | 02 | Cash |
| 1-550 | 06 | !!! Missing |
| 1-699 | 08 | Supplies |
| 1-999 | 06 | Inventory |
| 1-999 | 10 | !!! Missing |

**Note that I'm using SSMS**

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow david! i saw an entire text describing the mapping, but i can't see where this "record" thing. am i missing something? also, what have you tried? i think it needs some string operation like `left`, `right`, or `substring` maybe.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also note that SSMS is purely a client UI - the database engine is SQL Server.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa...the "record" that I was referring to is in the MAPPING table where the [Minor Code] can have a single and/or multiple value? i.e. in each MAPPING row (record) need to check determine the [Major code] and [Minor code] to return the desired Mapping Value

Comment: @Dale K...I'm a complete beginner with SQL query, and don't know the keyword to what I'm trying to accomplish here. The MAPPING table is what I had in mind when doing it in MS Excel. But because of thousands of [Major Code] and [Minor Code] and it could increase, thus it's dynamic and won't be feasible to have each individual major code and minor code combinations to describe the 'Mapping'. Thus, what I had shown is the simplest to get to the Mapping that we'd like to achieve.

Comment: @David.L on excel you can use `if`-else pairs but on sql server you can use [`case`-`when` pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). you can extract the 3 characters from major code using [`right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). i hope those clues can help you to get started.